# Typescript: Getting correct inference type when using conditional mapped keys

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, mapped-types, conditional-types

I'm trying to use [Conditional Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) to get only allow keys of an object that are of a particular type as a parameter in a function.

However, I'm running into an issue in that the correct type is not being inferred when I do so.

I've created an example to demonstrate ([view on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20TraversableType%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TypeOne%20extends%20TraversableType%7B%0D%0A%20%20typeNotTraversable%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20typeTwo%3A%20TypeTwo%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TypeTwo%20extends%20TraversableType%7B%0D%0A%20%20typeTwoNotTraversable%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20typeOne%3A%20TypeOne%3B%0D%0A%20%20typeThree%3A%20TypeThree%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TypeThree%20extends%20TraversableType%7B%0D%0A%20%20typeThreeProp%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TraversablePropNames%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20TraversableType%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fgiven%20start%20object%2C%20return%20%0D%0Afunction%20indexAny%3CT%20extends%20TraversableType%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(startObj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20startObj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fsame%20thing%2C%20but%20with%20only%20%22traversable%22%20keys%20allow%0D%0Afunction%20indexTraverseOnly%3CT%20extends%20TraversableType%2C%20K%20extends%20TraversablePropNames%3CT%3E%3E(startObj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20startObj%5Bkey%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20t2%3A%20TypeTwo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20keyType%20%3D%20keyof%20TypeTwo%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22typeTwoNotTraversable%22%20%7C%20%22typeOne%22%20%7C%20%22typeThree%22%20%7C%20%22name%22%0D%0Atype%20keyType2%20%3D%20TraversablePropNames%3CTypeTwo%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22typeOne%22%20%7C%20%22typeThree%22%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20r1%20%3D%20indexAny(t2%2C%20'typeOne')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20TypeOne%0D%0Alet%20r2%20%3D%20indexTraverseOnly(t2%2C%20'typeOne')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20TypeOne%20%7C%20TypeThree)):

```
interface TraversableType{
  name: string;
}

interface TypeOne extends TraversableType{
  typeNotTraversable: string;
  typeTwo: TypeTwo;
  typeThree: TypeThree;
}

interface TypeTwo extends TraversableType{
  typeTwoNotTraversable: string;
  typeOne: TypeOne;
  typeThree: TypeThree;
}

interface TypeThree extends TraversableType{
  typeThreeProp: string;
}


type TraversablePropNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TraversableType ? K : never }[keyof T];


//given start object, return 
function indexAny<T extends TraversableType, K extends keyof T>(startObj: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return startObj[key]; 
}

//same thing, but with only "traversable" keys allow
function indexTraverseOnly<T extends TraversableType, K extends TraversablePropNames<T>>(startObj: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return startObj[key]; 
}

let t2: TypeTwo;

type keyType = keyof TypeTwo;                  // "typeTwoNotTraversable" | "typeOne" | "typeThree" | "name"
type keyType2 = TraversablePropNames<TypeTwo>; // "typeOne" | "typeThree"

let r1 = indexAny(t2, 'typeOne');              // TypeOne
let r2 = indexTraverseOnly(t2, 'typeOne');     // TypeOne | TypeThree
```

Notice how when using `K extends keyof T` the `indexAny` function is able to infer the correct return type.

However, when I try to use the `TraversablePropNames` conditional mapped type to defined the key, it doesn't know if it's `TypeOne` or `TypeTwo`.

Is there some way to write the function so that it will ONLY allow keys of `TraversableType` AND will infer the type correctly?

### UPDATE:

Interestingly... it seems to work 1 property deep IF I wrap the method in a generic class and pass the instance in (instead of as the first param).  However, it only seem to work for one traversal... then it fails again:

```
class xyz<T>{
  private traversable: T;
  constructor(traversable: T) {
    this.traversable = traversable;
  }

   indexTraverseOnly<K extends TraversablePropNames<T>>(key: K): T[K] {
    return this.traversable[key]; 
  }

  indexTraverseTwice<K extends TraversablePropNames<T>, K2 extends TraversablePropNames<T[K]>>(key: K, key2: K2): T[K][K2] {
    return this.traversable[key][key2]; 
  }
}

let t2: TypeTwo;
let r3Obj = new xyz(t2);
let r3 = r3Obj.indexTraverseOnly('typeOne'); // TypeOne (WORKS!)

let r4 = r3Obj.indexTraverseTwice('typeOne', 'typeThree'); // TypeTwo | TypeThree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `T` appears in two positions for the function call (both standalone and in `K`) there are basically two positions that can determine the type of `T`. Now usually typescript can handle such cases for simple situations, but using the mapped type will cause it to give up on inferring the type of `K`.

There are several possible solutions, one of which you discovered, that is to fix `T` first. You did it with a class, you could also do it with a function that returns a function:

```
function indexTraverseOnly2<T extends TraversableType>(startObj: T) {
  return function <K extends TraversablePropNames<T>>(key: K): T[K] {
    return startObj[key];
  }
}

let r3 = indexTraverseOnly2(t2)('typeThree');     // TypeThree
```

The other solution would be to specify the constraint that `K` must a key in `T` that has a value of `TraversableType` in a different way, you could say that `T` must extend `Record<K, TraversableType>` meaning that key `K`  must have the type `TraversableType` regardless of any other properties.

```
function indexTraverseOnly<T extends Record<K, TraversableType>, K extends keyof any>(startObj: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return startObj[key]; 
}
```

**Edit**

To traverse multiple types you will need to defined multiple overloads. There is unfortunately no way to do this in a single overload since the parameters are interdependent. You can define up to a reasonable number of overloads:

```
function indexTraverseOnly<T extends Record<K, TraversableType & Record<K2,TraversableType& Record<K3,TraversableType>>>, K extends keyof any, K2 extends keyof any, K3 extends keyof any>(startObj: T, key: K, key2:K2, key3:K3): T[K][K2][K3]
function indexTraverseOnly<T extends Record<K, TraversableType & Record<K2,TraversableType>>, K extends keyof any, K2 extends keyof any>(startObj: T, key: K, key2:K2): T[K][K2] 
function indexTraverseOnly<T extends Record<K, TraversableType>, K extends keyof any>(startObj: T, key: K): T[K]
function indexTraverseOnly(startObj: any, ...key: string[]): any {
  return null; 
}

let t2: TypeTwo;

let r1 = indexTraverseOnly(t2, 'typeOne');     // TypeOne
let r2 = indexTraverseOnly(t2, 'typeOne', 'typeTwo'); // TypeTwo
let r3 = indexTraverseOnly(t2, 'typeOne', 'typeTwo', 'typeThree'); // TypeThree
```

Comment: so is there anyway to traverse multiple levels deep, while restricting the keys which can be used to a type?  My use case I need to index up to five times. 

Also, on your second type method, is there any reason you didn't use `<T extends Record<K, TraversableType>, K extends keyof T>`?

Comment: @NSjonas  `K` just need to be a key, if you defined `K extends keyof T`, `T` and `K` are mutually recursive and `K` will end up being just a key anyway .. the restriction is in the fact that `T extends Record<K, TraversableType>`. For multiple levels you need to define multiple overloads ... I'll add an update ..

Comment: thank you so much!  I've spent sooo many hours struggling to figure this out now

Comment: so sorry to keep bothering you, I'm sure you are a busy man.  But it is it possible to do this in a way that:

1: Will allow autocomplete on the key
2: Will will throw an error if the key isn't valid?

For example, right now this doesn't complain at all:
`let r3 = indexTraverseOnly(t2, 'typeOne', 'typeTwo', 'tghjkasd'); // valid`

Comment: just to clarify, I'm writing a query generator library for a SOQL-esk language, so getting the typings in the parameters is actually what matters most.

Comment: @NSjonas I think it would work with the function that returns a function approach.. I'd need to test and I justeft work..

Comment: no worries! Thanks for you help!  I'll try to figure it out using that approach (might bug you again if I get really really stuck)

Comment: @NSjonas or we might force an error using a conditional type.. I'll try to add a solution later

Comment: I've gotten it to work using the curry function approach. I'll need to adjust my libraries "API", but overall not a big deal.  The only thing I'm not sure about is how to implement the different relationship depths.  Ideally it could be overloaded so that a single function could be called, instead of having to call a specific function (EG `indexTraverse3()`) that traverse the number of times you need