# Resolve object item type correctly, when using conditionally mapped keys (key applied back on the object)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-types

Hopefully, I just miss something and someone could point it out, but I ran into a problem, when TS can not determine correctly the type of an object item value, taken by a property, the name of which was conditionally mapped from that very item type.

Assume we have an interface, some properties of which contain an array of a specific type.

```
interface Aa {
  foo: string;
  bar: Bb[];
}

interface Bb {
  zap: string;
}
```

Based on that, creating a new interface, which would restrict the 'prop' property to be equal only to 'bar' in our case, where B[] is stored. Imagine, there will be other but similar type combinations.

```
interface Kk<T, U> {
  prop: {[keyT in keyof T]: T[keyT] extends U[] ? keyT : never}[keyof T];
}

const key: Kk<Aa, Bb> = {
  prop: 'bar'
};
```

And it works as expected: 'key' cannot have value of 'prop' other than 'bar'.

However, when it comes for referencing value by that property there comes a TS problem, that item does not have forEach method.

```
let b1: Bb = { zap: 'b1' }, b2: Bb = { zap: 'b2' };
let a1: Aa = { foo: 'foo', bar: [b1, b2] };

function f<T, U>(k: K<T, U>, a: T) {
    a[k.prop].forEach((b: Bb) => { console.log(b); }); // TS no forEach 
    return k.prop;   
}
```

As it's described in [relevant post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169687/typescript-getting-correct-inference-type-when-using-conditional-mapped-keys) it seems like the problem is that T occurs in the function signature 'too often'.
And if we try to use the result of the function as a key, there is no error.

```
let k = f(key, a1);
a1[k].forEach(() => {});
```

Still I bear a hope that there is a clean solution for this and I miss something.

Link to [TS playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnJge3wC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkAjOKEgIQG0BdOgXyy1CRYiFK0z0AXnAAOJcpRC0sfAeGjwkyANIAeACoAaZAFUAfONzSo+WZnYBrCAE89yUMkdP8MZHs4k9B2c-ZAgAD0gQABNSEy5kAH4PYOQSEAgAN2geIK8fP15+BHwQcmSnEl1UI1ZzAF4LZCsbEgByJihW5TosABsIMEYARjZkBoxkKVtWqaHW5B4jBgAmUfHJmTap5fmeOn7BuBG0McbcAmJkVovWg3pcDpJ2BiGl5c47lRgAVxAEMGAJTw+iMZgAFPZKiCTKYjHAAgBKM7IOAOAB0zWknDRBCgAFFEAALMFghhsJF1cwTYqlfD9NG9fBUUkImgLVn3ZBQAbfKAgDwY6zSNm4ZT8A4eU4wCHOOFDDlHBzY3EEhDEsEUqk8DlYIA)